# PowerShell ConvertFrom-Json conversion error

Tags: json, powershell

My PowerShell ConvertFrom-Json for the below throws the "Invalid JSON primitive" error.

```
{
    "ScriptEndTime": "19 April 2022 10:26:32",
    "AbortReason": "Server Offline",
    "Server": "Server3",
    "ScriptStartTime": "19 April 2022 10:25:55",
    "Notes": "",
    "NumberOfReboots": 0,
    "Abort": true,
    "UserAccount": "Contoso\\ContosoAdmin"
} {
    "OS": "Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard",
    "Abort": false,
    "KB5011560": "Succeeded",
    "Server": "Server4.contoso.co.uk",
    "IPAddress": "3.3.3.3"
}
```

I even tried to validate the above using jsonlint.com and it shows **Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']', got '{'** error

What am I missing? Thanks.

**Update: 20/04/2022**

Below is what was happening internally in my case:

```
$MyHt1 = @{}    
$MyHt1.Server = "Server1"
$MyHt1.StartTime = '1/1/2021 09:30:30 AM'
$MyHt1."" = "Succeeded" #my script was setting empty key here which is the source of the issue

$MyHt2 = @{}    
$MyHt2.Server = "Server2"
$MyHt2.StartTime = '2/2/2022 09:30:30 PM'
$MyHt2."KB54231" = "Pending"

$JsonOutputArray = @($MyHt1, $MyHt2  | Foreach-Object { ConvertTo-Json -InputObject $_ })
$JsonOutputArray | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json #throws runtime error here due to empty key
```

Looks like PowerShell hash table allows an empty key. That was the root cause of this issue which later resulted in runtime error during json conversion. Interestingly, ConvertTo-Json allows empty hash table key but fails with ConvertFrom-Json

Comment: There's a comma missing between `}` and `{`

Comment: that, and a surrounding array `[` ... `]`.

Comment: The 2 objects above are auto-generated through PowerShell. For each object, I first build a hashtable in a separate runspace and then use ConvertTo-Json to output the result in the end. The wrapper runspace factory script collects these individual json output and then rehydrate it back to json using ConvertFrom-Json. No manual fiddling with any output involved. Besides the behaviour is not consistent. Sometimes it does work as expected.

Comment: It makes me think the Convert*-JSON cmdlets  have an obscure bug.

Comment: @Steve "No manual fiddling", except for manually concatening the individual outputs from `ConvertTo-Json` together? Show us the code :-)

Comment: In the runspace for e each input, the output is generated using $PatchingStatusHashTable | ConvertTo-Json . The wrapper host script collects the results and then convert it back to json using ConvertFrom-Json. I let the json cmdlets to do the work. Does that construe as manual fiddling?

Comment: The code is a couple of thousands of lines. The solution has been working for the last one year without any issues. Only last night ran into this.

Comment: It sounds like you're taking multiple independent outputs from `ConvertTo-Json` and feeding them to `ConvertFrom-Json` as a single document (hence the error). You probably just need to insert a `foreach` loop somewhere before calling `ConvertFrom-Json`, but hard to tell exactly without seeing code that reproduces your issue :)

Comment: I see what you mean. Will give it a try. Thanks. :-)

Comment: @Steve Here's an example of what I'm talking about: https://gist.github.com/IISResetMe/b23a5c1aa2827ce5db30f8bbfbeb4afa

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Finally got to the bottom of it. KB5001148 released this month wasn't playing ball with psWindowsUpdate PS community module. The Get-WUHistory command was returning blank for this KB number while returning other fields such as install status intact. I was using this KB number as the key in my custom hashtable. So convert to json was throwing a fit due to this blank key. That explains why my solution was working in the last one year until this month. That said, your suggestion to split the code into 2 lines has helped me uncover another subtle bug. So thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

Those are two separate JSON files to add them in one JSON file you should ad them in one bracket {} and the other items are separated by ","
as the following :

```
{ 
    name1:{
                "ScriptEndTime": "19 April 2022 10:26:32",
                "AbortReason": "Server Offline",
                "Server": "Server3",
                "ScriptStartTime": "19 April 2022 10:25:55",
                "Notes": "",
                "NumberOfReboots": 0,
                "Abort": true,
                "UserAccount": "Contoso\\ContosoAdmin"
            },

    name2:{
                "OS": "Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard",
                "Abort": false,
                "KB5011560": "Succeeded",
                "Server": "Server4.contoso.co.uk",
                "IPAddress": "3.3.3.3"
            }
}
```